# "No te lo vas a creer" -- other ways to say this?

Tags: reflexivos, infinitivo, complemento-directo

I've seen the phrase ["no te lo vas a creer"](https://www.spanishdict.com/translate/no%20te%20lo%20vas%20a%20creer%2C%20pero%20saqu%C3%A9%20una%20f%20en%20el%20examen) in a few places, and I'm wondering whether I could say this differently.

Could I say the following, **or something similar**? "No vas a creertelo."

Comment: Yes, the reordering that you suggest is perfectly idiomatic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tanto

"No **te** **lo** vas a creer"

como

"No vas a creér**telo**".

son correctas.

Otras variantes parecidas en similares y diferentes contextos y personas pueden ser;

- ¡Ni te imaginas! / ¡Jamás lo hubiera imaginado!
- No te lo puedes imaginar. / No lo puedo concebir.
- Ni en un millón de años (lo hubiera imaginado, me, te lo hubiera/s figurado).
- No vas a dar crédito (a lo que te voy a decir). / No doy crédito.
- Después de esto, ya no sabes que pensar. / Después de esto, ya no se que pensar.
- Ni lo sospechas (lo que ha ocurrido).
- Ni te lo hueles (lo que ha pasado).
- ¿A que no sabes qué ? (Cuando se dice en el contexto de algo que no puedes creer)
- ¿Sabes qué? (Cuando se dice en el contexto de algo que no puedes creer)
- ¡Adivina! (Cuando se dice en el contexto de algo que no puedes creer)

Todas ellas poseen curiosidad, intriga, sospecha o quizás una noticia sorpresa de última hora.